# Is there a way to call process builder from Apex?

Tags: apex, process-builder

With the roll out of sub-processes, it seems like there would be a way to call a process builder from apex, but I'm not finding anything in the documentation.  Does anyone know if you can call a process builder from apex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is one way to do this using a http callout using a Named Credential to Actions REST API to call Flow or Invocable Process.

See link below for additional details.
https://douglascayers.com/2016/10/31/how-to-invoke-process-builder-from-flow/

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce introduced Platform Events, that can be fired from Apex, and subscribed directly by Processes:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm

Answer (score 0):

From Apex we cannot call process builder's process, but reverse is true.

Process Builder process can only be get called from other process.

Comment: Technically, from Apex you can make http request to [Actions REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_flow.htm). However, to make callout requires no other DML to have occurred so might have to do it asynchronously. See [Starley Flynn's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/180653/987).